# Store jQuery scripts in JS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, callback

I have a function with a variable called callback

```
function test(callback){

    // Some code

    callback;

}
```

When I call this function I used to insert a one liner into callback

eg. `test($('#elem').hide());`

Now I want to put multiple lines in here as the callback. I tried this but it does not appear to work.

```
var resetc = function(){

    $('.access').removeClass('viz');

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.access').find('.input.wheel').removeClass('viz');
        $('.access').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    },1000);
}

                        test(resetc);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with callback?

Comment: I want to execute some additional code once the function is complete

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing the function reference. You can use the callback variable to execute the function which it is referring. like

```
function test(callback) {
    // Some code
    callback();
}
```

You statement `test($('#elem').hide());` is having no effect as you are passing the output of `$('#elem').hide()` to your method test and statement `callback;` actually is not performing anything.

You need to change your function call for `test($('#elem').hide());` with

```
test(function() {
    $('#elem').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code doesn't do what you think. To call a callback, you need to put `()` after it:

```
function test(callback) {
    // some code
    callback();
}
```

If you fix that, `test(resetc);` will do what you want.

The reason you didn't notice this in your first test is because when you write

```
test($('#elem').hide());
```

you're executing `$('#elem').hide()` **before** calling `test`, it's not being done when `test` runs the callback. You need to pass a function to defer the execution until the callback is called:

```
test(function() {
    $('#elem').hide();
});
```